# Django Permissions App

Tags: django, django-permissions

I've the following models.

```
class Ads(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_price = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User)

class AdImages(models.Model):
    """Contain ad images uploaded by the user."""

    image = models.FileField(upload_to='ad/', blank=True, null=True)  # can be images/Videos.
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ads)
```

I'm able to create `Ad` and `AdImages` objects, but I want that only the user who created those objects should be able to edit/delete those objects. How can I do it?

I've read about Django permissions, but not able to implement the same. Not sure how those permissions work, inbuild permissions `auth_permissions`?

How do I apply permissions on objects?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just add a model field with the username that created the object. Then reference against the field to determine if current `user == creator`, then show options to allow for edit or deletion. Or if the `seller` you have is the user who created then reference that field.